# How to apply a ruby version patch in elastic-beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are running our application on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk and want to update the version of ruby we are using to the latest patch version and can't figure out what the best way to do so is. I think we might be able to using the `container_commands` in the configuration but am not sure if that is the right way to do so.

Is the right way just to specify the patch level in the Gemfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set in your gemfile the ruby version, for example:

```
ruby "2.0.0"
```

Or, if you want to set the engine, engine_version and etc:

```
ruby "1.9.3", :engine => "jruby", :engine_version => "1.7.8"
```

So basically you should change the version according to your need.
Take a look on the complete list of the ruby versions [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#ruby-versions)

I hope this helps.

Comment: This answer is for Heroku. Does Elastic Beanstalk respect the same `ruby` declaration in the `Gemfile`?